# Openpop Dll file for a VB project

Tags: openpop

I would like to use openpop with a VB .Net project and I think the simplest method would be to use a DLL but can anyone tell me where I can get the Dll from please?

Answer (score 1):

You can NuGet it from https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenPop.NET/

At your Package Manager Console (Visual Studio), type:

```
Install-Package OpenPop.NET
```

Comment: Many thank that look to work well thank you for your answer